# .net Support in Google App engine

Tags: .net, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is .net runtime supported by Google App engine? I see we can use custom runtime to use other runtimes other than the ones directly supported by GAC.

We use .net heavily and are planning to move to a cloud solution and hence evaluating GAC.

Comment: Don't think this is right place to ask such questions, Try appengine google groups instead. PS by custom runtime you probably mean Google Cloud Instances? it's little bit different thing

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I don't know about SO's opinion but Google would like to see more of this stuff on SO then groups since SO keeps questions more organize. And custom runtimes is a feature of Managed VMs, which is closer to App Engine than Google Compute Engine (the instances), so it's a fair question.

Answer (score 3):

You can run your .Net code on Windows instances in Google Compute Engine.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows

From there, you can run your existing code, or take advantage of Google's services like Pub/Sub.  Here's a sample that shows .Net code being invoked from an app-engine front end.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub-shout-csharp

Comment: Also, if app engine is desired, the custom runtime route still works. One could use Mono and Docker's [official mono image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mono/) as a starting point.

Comment: But if I use a docker can I use the app engines api's?